# Check if entries are seperated by comma

Tags: javascript

I have several strings that contain entries separated by a comma, for example:

```
('ENTRY1', 'ENTRY2','ENTRY3')
```

As you can see, each entry is separated by a comma, either with or without a following blank.

How can I check with JavaScript if between each entry there is always a comma (with or without a blank).

The string can contain 0 to n entries.

Requirement: A script should return true or false based on the following example:

```
('ENTRY1', 'ENTRY2','ENTRY3') // return false
('ENTRY1' 'ENTRY2''ENTRY3')   // return true
('ENTRY1','ENTRY2''ENTRY3')   // return true
```

false = correct entry
true  = false entry

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `How can I check with JavaScript if between each entry there is always a comma (with or without a blank).` Would you please show us an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: have you ever considered using array?

Comment: You know how many entries are there? Or if there is no comma between any 2 entries, how they are separated?

Comment: The number of entries is not set to a defined number.

Comment: how about using regex? something like this expression - ['\w']+[,] - and count get the number of matches? or the matches themselves if you need the values. try to explain a little more about what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example:

```
('ENTRY1', 'ENTRY2','ENTRY3') // return false
('ENTRY1' 'ENTRY2''ENTRY3')   // return true
('ENTRY1','ENTRY2''ENTRY3')   // return true
```

Since entry is enclosed within single quote (`' '`), you can do

```js
function validate(entries) {
  if (entries.replace(/ /g, '').indexOf("''") > -1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

//Test case
var entries1 = "('ENTRY1', 'ENTRY2','ENTRY3')";
var entries2 = "('ENTRY1' 'ENTRY2''ENTRY3')";
var entries3 = "('ENTRY1','ENTRY2''ENTRY3')";
document.write(validate(entries1)+","+validate(entries2)+","+validate(entries3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use split like this:

```
var splitArray = someString.split(',');
```

for explicitly stating its separated by a `,`

Comment: Could you please tell me why you down voted this post? What is wrong with this. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly,
you can use regex for this to make sure there's always a comma between two items if your string is exactly as you mention above

```
var str = "('ENTRY1', 'ENTRY2','ENTRY3')";

str = str.match(/'([^'])+'/g).join(',');
```

since you updated your code you can use this code to achieve following

```
('ENTRY1', 'ENTRY2','ENTRY3') // return false
('ENTRY1' 'ENTRY2''ENTRY3')   // return true
('ENTRY1','ENTRY2''ENTRY3')   // return true
```

false = correct entry true = false entry

```js
function isNotOK(str){
  var match = str.match(/'[^,i]+'/g);
  var len = str.match(/'([^'])+'/g)
  if(match && len && match.length === len.length){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
    
var str1 = "('ENTRY1', 'ENTRY2','ENTRY3')";
var str2 = "('ENTRY1' 'ENTRY2''ENTRY3')";

document.write(isNotOK(str1) + ' , ' +  isNotOK(str2));
```